# Draw the combinatorial embedding of a generic planar graph

Tags: java, graph, planar-graph

I have the combinatorial embedding of a generic planar graph (vertices, edges, the cyclic ordering of edges around vertices and the external face) and I need to draw it.

The vertices must be adimensional and the drawing must comply with the defined cyclic ordering of edges around vertices (and with the external face), even if the input graph is not 3-connected or maximal planar.

It would be better if the drawing algorithm was already implemented (perhaps in a Java library), but a paper with the algorithm explanation is still sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/igraphm-a-mathematica-interface-for-igraph.html), which is a Mathematica package for use in complex networks and graph theory research.

```
    Needs["IGraphM`"]
    s = <|1 -> {11, 12, 13}, 2 -> {3, 20, 8}, 3 -> {2, 4, 42}, 
       4 -> {3, 5, 28}, 5 -> {4, 6, 34}, 6 -> {5, 7, 46}, 
       7 -> {6, 10, 30}, 8 -> {2, 22, 9}, 9 -> {8, 23, 10}, 
       10 -> {9, 25, 7}, 11 -> {1, 15, 14}, 12 -> {1, 27, 29}, 
       13 -> {1, 32, 31}, 14 -> {11, 16, 22}, 15 -> {11, 19, 16}, 
       16 -> {15, 17, 14}, 17 -> {16, 18, 21}, 18 -> {17, 19, 24}, 
       19 -> {18, 15, 25}, 20 -> {2, 41, 26}, 21 -> {17, 23, 22}, 
       22 -> {21, 8, 14}, 23 -> {21, 24, 9}, 24 -> {23, 18, 25}, 
       25 -> {24, 19, 10}, 26 -> {20, 39, 27}, 27 -> {26, 35, 12}, 
       28 -> {4, 29, 40}, 29 -> {28, 12, 35}, 30 -> {7, 31, 45}, 
       31 -> {30, 13, 36}, 32 -> {13, 33, 36}, 33 -> {32, 34, 43}, 
       34 -> {33, 5, 44}, 35 -> {29, 27, 37}, 36 -> {32, 38, 31}, 
       37 -> {35, 39, 40}, 38 -> {36, 43, 45}, 39 -> {37, 26, 41}, 
       40 -> {37, 42, 28}, 41 -> {39, 20, 42}, 42 -> {41, 3, 40}, 
       43 -> {38, 33, 44}, 44 -> {43, 34, 46}, 45 -> {38, 46, 30}, 
       46 -> {45, 44, 6}|>;(*combinatorial embedding*)
      g = IGAdjacencyGraph[s] (*generate the graph)
 Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> IGEmbeddingToCoordinates[s], 
 VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Center], VertexSize -> 0.5, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> 6, ImageSize -> Large, 
 VertexStyle -> ColorData["Legacy", "LemonChiffon"], 
 EdgeStyle -> Darker@ColorData["Legacy", "IndianRed"]
 ]
```

[image]

As for which algorithm to use, I recommend contacting developer Szabolcs Horvát.